# AWS CLI, kms Uknown output type: q

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kms

When attempting to call `aws kms get-parameters-for-import --key-id .... --wrapping-algorithm RSAES_OAEP_SHA_1 --wrapping-key-spec RSA_2048` I receive an error `Unknown output type: q`.  I'm following the instructions in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/importing-keys-get-public-key-and-token.html but not having luck with that step.

Comment: Do other aws cli commands work? You might have an invalid output type set in the cli tool's config file?

Comment: Trying to update `awscli` couldn't hurt either.

Comment: Agree with Mark, please run the aws configure again and set the valid output e.g. json or text.

Comment: @MarkB That was it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output.html), AWS CLI supports this four output formats:

- json
- yaml (Available in the AWS CLI version 2 only.)
- text
- table

According to the [AWS CLI configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html) topic you have three ways to specify the output format:

- Using the `output` option in a named profile in the `config` file

  `[default]`
  `output=text`
- Using the `AWS_DEFAULT_OUTPUT` environment variable

  `$ export AWS_DEFAULT_OUTPUT="table"`
- Using the `--output` option on the command line:

  `$ aws s3 ls --output json`